# Error when trying to sort the RecyclerView

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview, dialog

I have a `RecyclerView` with `item`, I need to open a `DialogFragment` by clicking the `LinerLayout`, and there was a `Button` in the DialogFragment that my `RecyclerView` will be sorted by clicking on.

Now I click on the button to crash the application with an error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String[] com.example.test.Attraction.FragmentAttractionRecyclerView.mArraysNames' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test.Attraction.DialogSort.sortArray_type(DialogSort.java:36)
        at com.example.test.Attraction.DialogSort.lambda$onCreateView$0$DialogSort(DialogSort.java:29)
        at com.example.test.Attraction.-$$Lambda$DialogSort$hNUzI3gzFGpf0diQdPCF44sgutU.onClick(lambda)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5692)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
```

How to fix it ? I suspect that the problem is due to the fact that the `sortArray_type` is not in the `Fragment` itself.

`Fragment` in which the `RecyclerView` is located

```
public class FragmentAttractionRecyclerView extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentAttractionRecyclerView";
    private RecyclerView mRec;
    public AdapterAttractions adapter;
    public ArrayList<ItemAttractions> exampleList;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public String[] mArraysNames;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        mArraysNames  = new String[]{"Baby островок", "Виражи", "Вокруг света", "5D кинотеатр"};
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
            }
        };

        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_test_2, container, false);
    }
    @SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "LongLogTag"})
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();

        LinearLayout dialog_button = requireView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);

        dialog_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog");
            DialogSort dialog = new DialogSort();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogSort");
        });


        SearchView searchView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void createExampleList() {
        exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Baby островок", "Детский", "60₽", 0));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Виражи", "Детский", "80₽", 1));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Вокруг света", "Детский", "50₽", 2));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_interactive, "5D кинотеатр", "Интерактивный", "120₽", 3));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_family, "Кокосовый страйк", "Детско-семейный", "85₽", 4));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Компас", "Экстримальный", "100₽", 5));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Лабиринт \"Тарзан\"", "", "", 6));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Лови волну", "", "", 7));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Лучный тир \"Робин Гуд\"", "", "", 8));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Муравейник", "", "", 9));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Полный улёт", "", "", 10));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Попрыжек", "", "", 11));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Предел эмоций", "", "", 12));
    }

    public void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.attraction_recycler);
        adapter = new AdapterAttractions(exampleList);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRec.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`DialogFragment`

```
public class DialogSort extends DialogFragment  {
    FragmentAttractionRecyclerView fragmentAttractionRecyclerView;
    ImageView img;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_sort, container, false);
        img = view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            {
                sortArray_type();
                sortArrayList_type();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    private void sortArray_type() {
        Arrays.sort(fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.mArraysNames);
        fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private void sortArrayList_type() {
        Collections.sort(fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.exampleList, (o1, o2) -> o1.get_attraction_type().compareTo(o2.get_attraction_type()));
        fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have defined the array "mArraysNames" in **onCreate**. Try it. You can also define it in **onViewCreated**.

```
public class FragmentAttractionRecyclerView extends Fragment {
        private static final String TAG = "FragmentAttractionRecyclerView";
        private RecyclerView mRec;
        public AdapterAttractions adapter;
        public ArrayList<ItemAttractions> exampleList;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        //public String[] mArraysNames;
        public static String[] mArraysNames = new String[]{"Baby островок", "Виражи", "Вокруг света", "5D кинотеатр"};

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
            /*mArraysNames  = new String[]{"Baby островок", "Виражи", "Вокруг света", "5D кинотеатр"};*/
            OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                @Override
                public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);
                }
            };
    
            requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_test_2, container, false);
        }
        @SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "LongLogTag"})
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            createExampleList();
            buildRecyclerView();
    
            ImageView sort_alphabet = requireView().findViewById(R.id.sort_alphabet);
    
            LinearLayout dialog_button = requireView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
    
            dialog_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog");
                DialogSort dialog = new DialogSort();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogSort");
            });
    
            sort_alphabet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sortArray_type();
                    sortArrayList_type();
                }
            });
    
            SearchView searchView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.searchView);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    
        public void createExampleList() {
            exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Baby островок", "Детский", "60₽", 0));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Виражи", "Детский", "80₽", 1));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Вокруг света", "Детский", "50₽", 2));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_interactive, "5D кинотеатр", "Интерактивный", "120₽", 3));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_family, "Кокосовый страйк", "Детско-семейный", "85₽", 4));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Компас", "Экстримальный", "100₽", 5));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Лабиринт \"Тарзан\"", "", "", 6));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Лови волну", "", "", 7));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Лучный тир \"Робин Гуд\"", "", "", 8));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Муравейник", "", "", 9));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Полный улёт", "", "", 10));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Попрыжек", "", "", 11));
            exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_extreme, "Предел эмоций", "", "", 12));
        }
    
        public void buildRecyclerView() {
            mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.attraction_recycler);
            adapter = new AdapterAttractions(exampleList);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            mRec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRec.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        private void sortArray_type() {
            Arrays.sort(mArraysNames);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    
        private void sortArrayList_type() {
            Collections.sort(exampleList, (o1, o2) -> o1.get_attraction_type().compareTo(o2.get_attraction_type()));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question, the problem is that `sortArray_type` is in` DialogSort`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Error:`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.example.test.Attraction.AdapterAttractions com.example.test.Attraction.FragmentAttractionRecyclerView.adapter' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test.Attraction.DialogSort.sortArray_type(DialogSort.java:37)
        at com.example.test.Attraction.DialogSort.lambda$onCreateView$0$DialogSort(DialogSort.java:29)
        at com.example.test.Attraction.-$$Lambda$DialogSort$hNUzI3gzFGpf0diQdPCF44sgutU.onClick(lambda)`

Comment: You can try using "mArraysNames" by keeping this data in a static class by calling it from there. But this is not the recommended method.

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe there is some kind of alternative?

Comment: Null control Check can be done. If Null, data is included.:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226110/discussion-between-buldog-and-kzncrda).